# transforming array into json - smarty

Tags: javascript, php, json, smarty

Suppose I have an array (dynamically generated from my php code)

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Sat' => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Sun' => string '10' (length=2)
```

and I want to get the following to put it inside a javascript variable

```
        {
            "x": 'Sat',
            "y": 6
        }{
            "x": 'Sun',
            "y": 10
        }
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Have you looked it up like 5 seconds on google ?

Comment: Hows smarty related to simple data?

Comment: Are you looking for it to do the transform or is a simple json_encode sufficient? i.e. I would expect desired output to be Sat : 6, Sun:10, not the x and y shown.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to convert it inside a smarty template? If so, you can execute normal php methods in smart templates by wrapping them in tags `{php}json_encode($array);{/php}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
$myArray = array(
    array(    
        "x" => "Sat",
        "y" => "6",        
    ),
    array(    
        "x" => "Sun",
        "y" => "10",        
    )
);

$json =  json_encode($myArray);

print_r($json);
```

Output: [{"x":"Sat","y":"6"},{"x":"Sun","y":"10"}]

Answer (score 3):

you could use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and pass it to javascript variable like:

```
$json = json_encode($your_array);
```

and in js:

```
var json_frm_php = <?php echo $json; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'json_encode' directly within smarty, or just assign a json_encode()'ed variable...

e.g.

```
// in your PHP script :
$myArray = array(
    array("x" => "Sat", "y" => "6",),
    array("x" => "Sun", "y" => "10",),
);
$smarty->assign('jsondata', json_encode($myArray));
$smarty->assign('rawdata', $myArray);
$smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

And then in the template :

```
<script> 
var data1 = {$jsondata};
var data2 = {$rawdata|@json_encode};
....
</script>
```

Which will render like :

```
<script>
var data1 = [{"x":"Sat","y":"6"},{"x":"Sun","y":"10"}];
var data2 = [{"x":"Sat","y":"6"},{"x":"Sun","y":"10"}];
...
</script>
```

See also : http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to put in a javascript variable this

```
    {
        "x": 'Sat',
        "y": 6
    },{
        "x": 'Sun',
        "y": 10
    }
```

so you have to first to wrap your variable `$jsonArray=json_encode($Array)` in your php code and then

```
{literal}
<script>
    var json = JSON.parse('{/literal}{$campaign->getStatsMembers()}{literal}'),final=[],final=[];
for(var key1 in json){
    for(var key2 in json[key1]){
        var tmp={"x":key2,"y":json[key1][key2]};
        final.push(tmp);
    }
}

console.log(final);
</script>
{/literal}
```

Btw, I used to `jQuery`, perhaps there exist a more convinient way to loop in your `json` variable !